# Is there a way to make a call from Spring boot API and read out text to receiver?

Tags: spring-boot, twilio-api

I can make a call out to a user using Twilio API, the challenge I am currently facing is passing the test API and it reads out the test message to the receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem.

I built a TwiML file, set all my parameters then passed it to the Call.creator method inside the Twilio library.
Detailed instructions can be found inside the API documentation here [Twilio Documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java/usage-guide#exceptions).

**Is there a better answer?**